# Is there a CloudWatch Alert and Notification metrics from Performance Insights?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, devops

Need to know if there are alert metrics in CloudWatch for RDS Performance insights. 
ie. Trigger and Alarm, whenever there is => high load, waits in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read  [Overview of Monitoring Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html)

> Amazon RDS automatically sends metrics to CloudWatch every minute for
>   each active database. You are not charged additionally for Amazon RDS
>   metrics in CloudWatch.
>
> You can watch a single Amazon RDS metric over a specific time period,
>   and perform one or more actions based on the value of the metric
>   relative to a threshold you set

You can create an alarm in RDS console and select the metric that is of your interest. Here is a snapshot to display that:

[image: ic]

Comment: Thanks @Juned A. I already refer to that link. I just want to ask the Performance Insights for example, the RDS Dashboard has Database Load measure Average Active Session (AAS) if Load Avg increases by 80% within 5min, it will trigger an alarm and will notify me via Email. Is this achievable within CloudWatch Alarm?

Comment: You can create an alarm in the cloudwatch console and select RDS to select the metric. You can select the SNS topic to send the notificaton when the threshold is reached. See the updated answer for cloudwatch create alarm for RDS

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS Performance Insights recently released a feature that sends key performance metrics from Performance Insights to Amazon CloudWatch. Using this feature, you can set alerts on these metrics.

When Performance Insights is enabled, it automatically sends the following three metrics to CloudWatch:

DBLoad
DBLoadCPU
DBLoadNonCPU

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/set-alarms-on-performance-insights-metrics-using-amazon-cloudwatch/